# Python regular expression: why optional match always returns null?

Tags: python, regex

I would like to catch the protocol in a text. If I do it by:

```
>>> d = re.search(re.compile(r".*(?P<protocol>(http\/\d\.\d)?) (?P<statuscode>\d{3})"), 'khkhjkhkhkh HTTP/1.1 303')
>>> d.groupdict()["protocol"]
```

the result would be empty, because to matches the protocol with .*, if I remove the '?' for the protocol, it works fine for this case but it does not work for the cases where the protocol is missing, for example 'khkhjkhkhkh 303'. I understand that it is confusing for regex to match the protocol instead of .* , but is there any work around this?

Comment: Not tested but try to replace the `.*` by the non-greedy `.*?`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the protocol pattern is optional, the first `.*` will match as much as possible (greedy) up to the mandatory status code pattern. As per the comment, you need the non-greedy variant: `.*?`.

You also need to match case insensitive, since your pattern has `http`, but the search string has `HTTP`.

Together:

```
>>> import re
>>> regex = re.compile(r".*?(?P<protocol>(http/\d\.\d)?) (?P<statuscode>\d{3})", re.I)
>>> match = regex.search('khkhjkhkhkh HTTP/1.1 303')
>>> match.groupdict()['protocol']
'HTTP/1.1'
```

(No need to escape the forward slash.)